# Render Object Array Properties In a Single Line

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an object like below. I need to render all the `subcategoryList` names to an Angular HTML template as single line. I use this kind of solution print array in a single line: `someObject.languages.join(' , ')`. What type of method can I use for this? I can't use `*ngFor` because it will render separate line for each object item.

```js
{
  firstName: " Hello",
  lastName: "World",

  category: [{
    catId: "1",
    catName: "SomeCat"
    subcategoriesList: [{
        subcatId: "5",
        subcatName: "SubSomeCat"
      },
      {
        subcatId: "6",
        subcatName: "SubSomeCat1"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    catId: "2",
    catName: "SomeCat2"
    subcategoriesList: [{
        subcatId: "9",
        subcatName: "SubSomeCat"
      },
      {
        subcatId: "10",
        subcatName: "SubSomeCat1"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Use span instead of div along with ngFor.

Comment: ^^ Or of course, pre-process the structure slightly so you have a single string (or at least single array you an use `join` on).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you can change the structure to a more flattened way. Or you can use span or inline div's.

```
<span *ngFor="let category of data.category">
    <span *ngFor="let subcategory of category.subcategoriesList">
        {{subcategory.subCatName}}
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you want all sub-catgeory names as single string in HTML. You can use angular pipe to transform the data before displaying it on UI.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'categoryNames'
})
export class CategoryNamesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(obj: unknown): any {
    return category
      .map(list =>
        list.subcategoriesList.map(subCatgeory => subCatgeory.name).join(', ')
      )
      .join(', ');
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<span> {{fullCatgeoryObj | categoryNames}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Arcteezy mentioned it can be done with a hack, By default DIV render as **`display:block`** and SPAN as **`display:inline`**.

```
----------------------------USING SPAN--------------------------
<br>
<span *ngFor="let category of myData.category">
     <span *ngFor="let subcategory of category.subcategoriesList">
        {{subcategory.subcatName}}
    </span>
</span>
<br>
----------------------------USING DIV------------------
<BR>
<div *ngFor="let category of myData.category" style="float:left">
  <div *ngFor="let subcategory of category.subcategoriesList" style="float:left">
        {{subcategory.subcatName}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tj1jqg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)